# Fetch Data from MySql to Windows Phone 8

Tags: mysql, listview, windows-phone-8

I create a windows phone 8 application. I have a remote MySql server and I want fetch data from it and display it in my windows phone 8 application in listview. How can I do this ?

Here is sample code of my listview

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Width="450">
        <ListBox.Items>

            <ListBoxItem Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                <ListBoxItem.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF421212" Opacity="0.6"/>
                </ListBoxItem.Background>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="453">
                    <Image Source="images/news.png" Width="92"></Image>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="353">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="News"                              Margin="10,0,0,0"             FontSize="30" Height="52"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Breaking news update" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="331" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="LstNews" Grid.Row="1" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="453" Background="#FF421212" Opacity="0.6">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Img_Path}" Width="92"></Image>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="353">
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding NewsHeader}" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30" Height="52"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NewsUpdate}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="331" Height="42" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

cs:

```
public void LoadSampleData()
{
    ObservableCollection<NewsData> obj = new ObservableCollection<NewsData>();
    obj.Add(new NewsData("Your Image Path", "Sample Header", "Sample Update"));
    obj.Add(new NewsData("Your Image Path1", "Sample Header1", "Sample Update1"));
    obj.Add(new NewsData("Your Image Path2", "Sample Header2", "Sample Update2"));
    LstNews.ItemsSource = obj;
}

public class NewsData
{
    public string Img_Path { get; set; }
    public string NewsHeader { get; set; }
    public string NewsUpdate { get; set; }

    public NewsData() { }
    public NewsData(string Img_Path,string NewsHeader,string NewsUpdate) 
    {
        this.Img_Path = Img_Path;
        this.NewsHeader = NewsHeader;
        this.NewsUpdate = NewsUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get data from server, So how cai i do that ?

Comment: That depends on your logic or service, How you fetch data from server. you get data from server n load it in observable Collection then it would work Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to let you app communicate with the database directly. Why not build a service which will serve data to your application directly. This has the following advantages :

- Your app can be ignorant of how the database is implemented. It would be served Json/Xml data based on how you design the service.
- You can reuse the service for any other apps in the future.

You can build the service using any of the widely popular frameworks available (.NET, PHP, Java, just to name a few).

Comment: Yah you are right but i am new on this platform. Can u please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: Well, Google is your friend :). As an example, I'd say look at a .NET REST based service application, which talks to your remote mySql database. And your app communicates to the REST endpoints.